# Youtube-dl downloading text file instead of audio file

Tags: python, audio, youtube-dl

I have some code for downloading youtube audio:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals


import youtube_dl



def my_hook(d):
    if d['status'] == 'finished':
        print('Done downloading, now converting ...')

ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',       
    'outtmpl': '%(title)s',        
    'noplaylist' : True,        
    'progress_hooks': [my_hook],  
}

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['url'])
```

but when it finishes, the file looks something like this, but a lot longer:

```
�І�#:�'��llQ���ʸz
I<.�C#�!�$- �q�y{d�4�#C;�(w!z��=g�BX�!ūEkk�%��Y�SE��4/��M(gw>7�\l0Lx�gI�X�D�eW/H�}.�   "8yV
+��s�$hڧ_[j�s�{�Ԑ�D�a=��SNN�M�7�;�b}�b�>�=�res�r�s.�9:�8�P�(�M�C���B�6��Yj�$�g&MP�cr&�Y&��R�a�E��j�nvIo��Fr�ZdT)Ş�s�u�̳���>�1�iBՑ�"0 [�,F�ъȕ}(g�v�!�J�V+��q� g�δ2�c!+�D1{R�7�$�8܎G/��P^�r�#�~D�~bԕC!�3f�X�60��j��1I)b��r8�Du��)�MXԕa��J�`�y
�bWf�m:q�)��S��T$JkUj�j�EJ� nf�i�gy���7�ݗ�
-vtb&�+}�bѣz�(Ii�W@ξ%<��s1�dD�n�-�N�F�)n�v�r�ȕ�i�ʮձ%��(@q�n�ɱ�
U�ݟ_\�
�C]�Mf�ʣ�ikDA� 5LrS,�1A�%�Wg�gю� �ٍ��q!^�rW1Ws`�%U��j�K�]�eH�wHqj.�Ç67�ɯ�7<�h62f�a�'�Z]-�v�eEy$C�Ǉe7֗ioŮ�-!�ݢ�a XF0
l�RH�4�V���
�#�?u[8Ny�{�&{�Q�#��~�~�\|t�Ė�=:�n�t�ߥJM�%f�d�t
�t�w-g�ukP�F�Y2�b�$e�3�i�cu1��i�,�mX�$��GC$#FkU�ĸ�$�R�T�넝�JŻ�'�.=���;K�L�&��� �N#�z�\g�܈ғψ[f
&5'~�4�N�@^�ۏ
\�w�
```

Why is it doing this, and how do I convert it to audio? Do you use ffmpeg to convert it?

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to open an audio file in notepad, that's why it looks mangled.

Try opening it with a music player (windows music player, VLC etc). Adding `.ogg` to the end of the generated file might help.